# Why user_id not assigned comment_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to create a blog, and I have 3 models `post`, `user`, `comment`. When I created `comment`,  `comment.post_id` is `nil`. What am I doing wrong?

**comments_controller**

```
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

*edit*

**post.rb**

```
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
```

**comment.rb**

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
```

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Show your associations in those models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  @comment.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Source: [Answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062074/user-comment-association-not-working-comment-user-email-returns-no-method-err)

So, use following association as in source above.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work.

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
  @post.comments << @comment
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```